# Run code before shared library is loaded in C++

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, ld

I have a proprietary shared object library that runs a code before my application starts. It complains about an environment variable that is not defined. Despite the fact that I can define it on the system environment, I would like to make the definition on the run time within my application executable, before this library is loaded.
I've read that GCC is capable of defining some `_init` functions before the library loads. However, I'm unable to find how to call these functions.
Is there some way to run a code on the executable before the loader calls the init section of the libraries?

Comment: do you mean: `__attribute__((constructor)) void foo(void) { /*setup you environment variable*/};` ?

Comment: It doesn't work, because the application initializes the shared library before the application begins.

Comment: You can load the library dynamically using dlopen() after you have set up the operating environment.

Comment: But, will the executable link properly?